# Can we access the android application from server without installing onto mobile

Tags: android

I am new to Android, so I would like to know this:

Is there a way to access an application from a cloud server without installing an .apk?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web application, like Youtube.

Meaning you can either access it from Android browser or via WebView, but using WebView will mean the user has to download the application.

Learn more [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to access an application from a cloud server without installing an **.apk**?

Answer : No

If you want the app to be managed on cloud, you can create a webapp and wrap it using Android Webview. But still you need to install the app on the device.

Another way, you can create a webapp using User Interface Systems like Jquery Mobile or Sencha Touch (to look native) then host it on your server and ask you user to launch it through browser and add the webapp to their Android device Home screen. So the user no need to install the app and the app (but not native) will be available on his/her Home screen as a installed app.

Comment: do you have a example of this